# How to assign id to load mask

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am assigning id to load mask in configuration part, but still i can find auto generated id instead of config id.

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(myPanel, {msg:"Please wait...",id:"myMaskId"});
```

myMask.show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is OK, just use Ext.getCmp():

```
Ext.getCmp('myMaskId');
```

But better use itemId property and ComponentQuery:

```
new Ext.LoadMask(p, {
    msg: 'Mask 2',
    itemId: 'myItemId',
});

...

var m = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('component[itemId=myItemId]')[0];
```

Examples with id & itemId: http://jsfiddle.net/9EzZq/

Answer (score 0):

I had checked in my system.. it is giving your defined id..

my code

var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(" ", {msg:"Please wait...",id:"myMaskId"});

alert(myMask.id);

Comment: Its not setting id in dom. If i am trying to access by Ext.get("myMaskId"). its giving me null.